# seeking in a bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going to work with large bag files, offline. I am going to have to seek back and forth in the bag to find the data I need, i.e. some sort of random access. Before I start working on a hack of my own, I'd like to know if there is any standard approach implemented out there. Let say the goal is to be able to retrieve a message on topic X, at or near time T.

Note: this question is related: http://answers.ros.org/question/10852/playing-back-large-files-with-rosbag/

I am thinking that I could open a new View with the proper query (X,T). But I am wondering how long will it take. i.e. when opening a view, is it reading an index to open it in a constant time, or is it going to scan through the bag until it finds it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59624/seeking-in-a-bag-file/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-06-11**:
Did you finally found a solution ? Because I could be very interesting (for me, but also for everyone) if you could share what you found/did :-) Thanks !

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-06-12**:
It's still on my todo list. Once done i'll post my solution here (probably a couple of months)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like most of the work in a view query happens in [View::updateQueries](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosbag/html/c++/view_8cpp_source.html#l00254).  In particular, it uses `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` to find the desired ranges by searching over a timestamp index.  My C++ reference states that these are binary searches, with `O(log N)` complexity.  If you look in [Bag::doWrite](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosbag/html/c++/bag_8h_source.html#l00548), you can see this index being updated as new data is written to the bag file.

The other question you reference addresses time to load a bag-file from disk, but not time to seek within that bag file once loaded.  I haven't tested it, but (at first glance) it looks like view queries should be fairly quick, even in large bag files.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1